# Can an Ice Devil give a command to his Hellfire Engine by telepathy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, telepathy

Can Ice Devil (Monster Manual) give a command to his Hellfire Engine (Fiendish Codex II) by telepathy?

The Telepathic Bond spell says:
You forge a telepathic bond among yourself and a number of willing creatures, "each of which must have an Intelligence score of 3 or higher".

Answer (score 2):

## [Telepathy](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#telepathy) fails against creatures lacking language

The supernatural ability [telepathy](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#telepathy) that's possessed by the [ice devil](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#ice-devil) (*Monster Manual* 56), in part, says that a "creature with this ability can communicate telepathically with any other creature… that has a language" (316).

Although a hellfire engine "responds to… simple commands of its creator" or the commands of another creature the engine's been ordered by its creator to obey, a hellfire engine possesses the [new-style stat block](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dd/20060707a) entry of ***Languages*** none (*Fiendish Codex II* 119), rendering it telepathically immune.

The 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *Rary's [telepathic bond](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#telepathic-bond)* [div] (*Player's Handbook* 268-9) is a different effect entirely from an ice devil's telepathy supernatural ability, but the *bond* spell also wouldn't affect the engine as the engine has Intelligence as a [nonability](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#nonabilities) and the *bond* spell mandates its subjects have Intelligence scores of at least 3.